# Routing for nested categories

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I have a category structure set up in my CakePHP application which supports nested categories. That is, a category can have a child and/or a parent. The database columns for the `categories` table are: `id`, `parent_id`, `lft`, `rght`, `name`, `slug`.

I've already written all the CRUD logic for categories and posts relating to those categories.

As an example, say I have a category called `about` and a sub-category called `me`. I would like URLs like `mysite.com/about/me` to show all the posts related to the `me` category.

I'm having trouble working out how to route this request. If I just do `Router::connect('/:category', array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view'))` it will only work for `mysite.com/about`, and I can't just do `/:category/:category/:category` because it isnt at all scale-able.

How can I achieve routing for nested categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `*` [operator for routes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#connecting-routes).

If you *know* the routes will only have one sub-category, your route should be

```
Router::connect('/:category/*', 
                 array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view'))
```

That will match `mysite.com/about/me` and pass it to the action like this

```
CategoriesController->view('me')
```

`me` will be passed as parameter and you can do all the queries and etc inside that action.

If, however, the nesting of categories have a length you can't define, the approach is different. Let's say you also want to map an url like `mysite.com/about/me/2012/march`. Then the route rule can be

```
Router::connect('/:category/**', 
                 array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view'))
```

That double `**` is referred in the docs as

> Using a trailing double star, will capture the remainder of a URL as a single passed argument. This is useful when you want to use an argument that included a / in it

So, everything after the category will be passed as parameter. In this example it will call

```
CategoriesController->view('me/2012/march')
```

and in that action you'll have to do a parse of the parameter to get the nesting you want. I recommend extracting that function as a protected or private function in the controller

```
class Categories as AppController {
    public function view($url_params) {
        //it could be a string or an array or etc, depends on how you want to handle it
        $array = $this->_parseCategories($url_params);
    }

    protected function _parseCategories($stringUrl) {
        $subcategories = explode('/', $stringUrl);
        //add whatever else you want to do
        return $subcategories;
    }
}
```

You should adjust the routes as you need (I didn't include the passing of `:category`), and also change the controller a bit, but it should be scalable enough

Comment: `**` is exactly what I needed, thanks! However I just discovered another problem, my posts route is defined as `/:category/:slug`, so would that route and `/:category/**` not "collide" in certain circumstances?

Comment: Yes, in some circumstances it will collide. You should put the `/:category/:slug` *before* `/:category/**`. For urls like `about/me`, cake will use the `/:category/:slug`, for `about/me/please` it should use `**`. A solution for that could be changing the slug route with `/post/:category/:slug`, for example, so every single post will have an url like `post/about/me`. Or leave just the `**` and let `CategoryController->view($params)` handle if it's just one post or a list of sub-categories posts. (I like the second option, prettier urls... but the first is less stress for the controller...)